# Google analytics realtime data in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We have enabled [continuous export of Google Analytics data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7430726?hl=en) which means we get `ga_realtime_sessions_YYYYMMDD` tables with data dumps throughout the day.

These tables are – usually! – left in place, so we accumulate a stack of the realtime tables for the previous *n* dates (*n* does not seem to be configurable).

However, every once in a while, one of the tables disappears, so there will be gaps in the sequence of dates and we might not have a table for e.g. yesterday.

Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

It would be nice to know which guarantees we have, as we might rely on e.g. realtime data from yesterday while we wait for the “finished” `ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD` table to show up. The support document linked above does not mention this.

Comment: I've not experienced any loss of data with these tables, I'd suggest raising this with Google directly to find out where the loss is occurring, as to my knowledge you should not get gaps in the data. Would be interested to know more about what your using intra-day data for as I struggled to get useful data from it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [this help article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7430726#about), these internal ga_realtime_sessions_YYYYMMDD tables should not be used for queries and the ga_realtime_sessions_view_YYYYMMDD view should be used instead for your queries, in order to obtain the fresh data and to avoid unexpected results.

In the case you want to use data from some day ago while you wait for the internal ga_realtime_sessions_YYYYMMDD tables to be created for today, you can choose to copy the data obtained from querying the ga_realtime_sessions_view_YYYYMMDD view, into a separate table at the end of a day for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we use the view for queries. I'll look into copying the data we need from the realtime table at the end of the day, but it's still not clear to me how – and why – it can disappear and what guarantees we actually have regarding these tables – if any.

Comment: How the tables are deleted is related to the BigQuery Analytics export process. This question would be best answered by the Google Analytics team which can be contacted using [this link] (https://support.google.com/360suite/answer/6396567?hl=en).